# Outcome of [1][1] and [1][0] in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding the outcome of this in JavaScript as I don't really understand it. Why if I use this code it gets the next result:

```
var a =[1][1];
var b = [1][0];
if(a){console.log(true);}else{console.log( false);} --> returns false

if(b){console.log(true);}else{console.log(false);} --> returns true
```

How to explain the exact way of how JavaScript interprets these results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple actually, lets break it down:

```
var a =[1][1];
```

Broken down is:

```
var a = [1]; //An array with the value '1' at the 0 index
a = a[1]; //assigns a the result of the 1 index, which is undefined
```

Same with `b` - but `b` uses the `0` index, which is defined (as `1`);

`a` is `undefined` which is falsy, and `b` is 1 - which is truthy.

Comment: Thank you very much! I've got it now. I'll signal the answer after the time limiter goes away.:)

Answer (score 2):

Basicall you are using the value from an array with one element of `1`.

`a` gets `undefined`, because there is no element with the index of `1`.
`b` gets `1`, because of the element `1` at index `0`.

```js
var a = [1][1]; // undefined
var b = [1][0]; // 1

console.log(a); // undefined
console.log(b); // 1

if (a) {
  console.log(true);
} else {
  console.log(false);  // false
}

if (b) {
  console.log(true);  // true
} else {
  console.log(false);
}
```

Comment: Thank you also :) but  tymeJV explain it already,but i'm glad all of you helped out!